# Questions about moderncv - cventry, font size, location

Tags: fontsize, moderncv

I have several TeX questions for moderncv.

1. How can I shift the location of the name higher up, not to waste space at the top above my name, please?
2. How can I increase a bit the size of the fonts used for the address details?
3. Most important question:
   I have another CVentry definition. I would like to write 2012-2015 and below (maybe in smaller font size) the duration: 3 years, 2 years 5 months, 3months
   I assume it is like adding a row to the left column in the CVentry?
   Thank you.

My mini example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\usepackage{moderncvcompatibility}
\usepackage{moderncvstyleclassic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1.25in, left=1.25in, right=1.25in]{geometry}
%
\makeatletter  
\newcommand*{\CVentry}[6]{%
  \cvline{#1}{%
    {\bfseries#2}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{, {\slshape#3}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, #4}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
    %
    \ifx&#6&%
      \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#6\end{minipage}}\fi%
  }}%
\makeatother
%
\firstname{Manuel}
\familyname{Perez, PhD}
\address{20 b Street}{12345 NYC\protect\\USA[![enter image description here][1]][1]}
\phone{+41(0)12345678} 
\email{dummy@dummy.com} 
\extrainfo{Age: 20 $\bullet$ Nationality: USA}

\begin{document}
 \makecvtitle

\section{Work experience}
\CVentry{2012--2015}{Super job title}{Location}{Country}{}{Description of the mission.}
\end{document}
```

[image: Example with questions]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is just a little piece to get you going:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,ngerman,roman]{moderncv}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}               
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\definecolor{LinkColor}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}           %dunkelblau
%\definecolor{LinkColor}{rgb}{0,0,0}           %schwarz
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1.25in, left=1.25in, right=1.25in]{geometry}

\makeatletter  
\newcommand*{\CVentry}[7]{%
  \cvline{#1\\\small{#2}}{%
    {\bfseries#3}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
    %
    \ifx&#7&%
      \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi%
  }}%
\makeatother

\moderncvstyle{classic}  %Optionen: 'casual', 'classic', 'oldstyle', 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue}    %Optionen: 'blue', 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey', 'black'

\firstname{Manuel}
\familyname{Perez, PhD}
\address{20 b Street}{12345 NYC\protect\\USA}
\phone{+41(0)12345678} 
\email{dummy@dummy.com} 
\extrainfo{Age: 20 $\bullet$ Nationality: USA}

\begin{document}
 \newgeometry{top=0.5in}
 \makecvtitle

\section{Work experience}
\CVentry{2012--2015}{\textcolor{red}{3 years\\2 months}}{Super job title}{Location}{Country}{}{Description of the mission.}
\restoregeometry
\end{document}
```

Node the new argument #2 in the line `\cvline{#1\\\small{#2}}{%`. By changing `\small` to someting else (like `\scriptsize`), you can change the size of the year and months entries.

By issuing `\newgeometry{top=0.5in}` you change that parameter only. With `\restoregeometry` it is restored back to preamble settings. This way you can move the name and entries up a bit.

All in all, it's not a very good solution. But maybe good for a start. Here is the output:

[image]

Right now, I don't have more time. But if there are no better answers posted, I will try to look into it in more detail. I hope it helps!